# Calculate total sum of all values from all rows of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, cumulative-sum

I'm having a 2-dimensional array and I need to get the total sum of the values.

```
[
    [
        'agent_example1' => 0,
        'agent_example2' => 2,
        'agent_example3' => 0,
        'agent_example4' => 1,
        '' => 0,
    ],
    [
        'agent_example1' => 0,
        'agent_example2' => 1,
        'agent_example3' => 0,
        'agent_example4' => 0,
        '' => 0,
    ],
    [
        'agent_example1' => 0,
        'agent_example2' => 3,
        'agent_example3' => 0,
        'agent_example4' => 0,
        '' => 0,
    ],
]
```

Result should be `7`.

Comment: What result do you get when you take the sum of the values in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or even easier:

```
function crash_reporter($evaluation){

    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($evaluation as $agent){    
        unset($agent['time']);
        $sum += array_sum($agent);
    }
    echo $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try something like this:

```
function sum_2d_array($outer_array) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($outer_array as $inner_array) {
        foreach ($inner_array as $number) {
            $sum += $number;
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the sums of each sub-array (`$agent`), after your `foreach/unset` loop, like:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $evaluation));
```

Answer (score 0):

While I would use salathe's solution for this specific scenario, I'll offer some alternatives.

You can visit all leafnodes with a functional-style script via `array_walk_recursive()` by passing the result variable as a modifiable reference.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EC2Sg))

```
$result = 0;
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function ($v) use (&$result) {
        $result += $v;
    }
);
var_export($result);  // 7
```

---

Or use a recursive iterator with a classic loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CbiJgH))

```
$result = 0;
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY) as $value) {
    $result += $value;
} 
var_export($result);  // 7
```